# How many mappings are there between these two graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $P_{20}$ be a path of length 20 like so: $x_0$-$x_1$-$~\cdots~$-$x_{20}$ and $G$ a cycle of order 3.

Allegedly there are $3 \cdot 2^{20}$ mappings $P_{20}\rightarrow G$, which I don't quite see.

---

We defined a mapping $\Psi$ of graphs $(V,E)\rightarrow (V',E')$ as a pair of mappings $\Psi_1:V\rightarrow V'$ and $\Psi_2:E\rightarrow E'$, such that $\forall e\in E, e=[x_1,x_2],\; \Psi_2(e)=[\Psi_1(x_1),\Psi_1(x_2)]$

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix the image of $x_0$. There are three possibilities.

Since the edge $[x_0,x_1]$ gets mapped to one of the edges connected to the image of $x_0$, you have two choices: you either move clockwise or counter-clockwise.

The necessarily also fixes $x_1$.

Repeat this decision 20 times, once for each edge.

So you have

$$ \underbrace{3}_{\text{Number of possible starting points}} \times \underbrace{2 \times \cdots \times 2}_{\text{20 of them, one for each choice of direction for an edge}} $$

Comment: Oh, man, that was really simple. ;-) Thank you very much!